# SharePoint 2013 REST API : can't able to get "Calculated Fields"

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

It's been really strange, as per [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/office/dn600182.aspx#bk_FieldCalculated), they shows that Calculated fields can be get using REST query.
But when I am actually try REST queries like :

> http://Server/_api/web/Lists(guid'2B3BD6CD-172B-4320-898F-30BA1DA0928E')/Fields

or

> http://Server/_api/web/Lists(guid'2B3BD6CD-172B-4320-898F-30BA1DA0928E')/Fields/GetByTitle('Title of Calculated Field')

I could not find Calculated fields in the list of fields.

Can anyone please show the way to get Calculated fields using REST API??
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoint REST API does return Calculated fields in REST query. `FieldTypeKind` of calculated column is `17`. So make a GET request in following end-point.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list title')/Fields?$filter=FieldTypeKind eq 17
```

It will return your all calculated fields. Test and Explore more about REST API using my [SP REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-rest-client/ojnaikgchcnginnmkmkonmdglhjikokd).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue in SharePoint 2013 using the SharePoint 2010 URI when pulling data.

> $site + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/MyList()?"

See: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/235480/73740